# Fail to use include without getting an error:

Tags: php, include

I am trying to use this:

```
 include_once("PoliticalForum/StoredProcedure/User/number_login_attempts.php");
```

> Warning: include_once(../../untitled/sanitize_string.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\number_login_attempts.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '../../untitled/sanitize_string.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\number_login_attempts.php
>   on line 3

and this:

```
  include_once("/PoliticalForum/untitled/sanitize_string.php");
```

> Warning: include_once(/PoliticalForum/untitled/sanitize_string.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\number_login_attempts.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   '/PoliticalForum/untitled/sanitize_string.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PoliticalForum\StoredProcedure\User\number_login_attempts.php
>   on line 3

How can I import files safely without having those errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick one:

- Provide a valid path (paths that start with `/` are *absolute*, otherwise they are *relative*).
- Add the folder to the [include_path](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php).
- Use [class autoloading](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) (if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure the files can be found on the include path, because these errors mean the file cannot be found by PHP.

More info about include can be found in the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

I think those files you include each inlude other files (possibly with require or require_once). These files cannot be found which causes the include to fail.

Include is ignored if the file doesn't exist, but it fails if the file does exists but contains errors.

Comment: so I cant include a file, which has another include in it.. I need to keep all the include in the parent file.. that uses all the other files?

Comment: You can include files that include other files, but if the file you include is found, then the other file should also be found. All or nothing. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
include_once("PoliticalForum/StoredProcedure/User/number_login_attempts.php");
```

Above statement means the directory `PoliticalForum` is in the same directory of the file which has this statement.

You need to look into the directory structure you are using.

Alternatively, you could use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to locate all directories starting from root directory.

ForExample:

```
`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`/dirLevel1 // sub directory on root
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
include_once "PoliticalForum/StoredProcedure/User/number_login_attempts.php";

include_once"PoliticalForum/untitled/sanitize_string.php";
```

Comment: then try using require_once or its your path.